# Use my custom FluentValidation error message instead of the default one

Tags: c#, json, validation, fluentvalidation

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Category
{
Fruits = 0,
Vegetables = 1,
Others = 2
}
```

The property in the Domain layer:

```
public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
```

When I'm creating a resource using POST, if the values entered in Category does not exsit in the enum, I get the following error:

> "errors": { "$.category[0]": [
> "The JSON value could not be converted to Domain.Category. Path :$.category[0] | LineNumber:6 | BytePositionInLine: 23."]}

Instead of this error I want to use my message error using FluentValidation.

I have tried `RuleFor(x => x.Category.ToString()).IsEnumName(typeof(Category));` but had no success.

Do you know how can I use my message error? e.g: `.WithMessage("The category {x} doesn't exist")`

Comment: please post your validation rules. but it sounds like JSON parsing is failing.

Comment: try to add to constructor Category = new List<Category>();

Answer (score 0):

look in example:

```
void Main()
{
    
    var t = new Customer();
    t.Category.Add(Category.Fruits);
    t.Dump();
    
    var x = new CustomerValidator();
    x.Validate(t).Dump();
    
}

public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Category).Empty().WithMessage("not empty");
        RuleFor(x => x.Category).IsInEnum().WithMessage("in enum");
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public Customer(){
        Category = new List<Category>();
    }
}
public enum Category
{
    Fruits = 0,
    Vegetables = 1,
    Others = 2
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you indicate specifically what the fix is? All I see is a big clump of code and a screenshot. Please [edit] your answer to include a more obvious summary of how to fix the OP's issue.

Comment: exaple contains how to "Do you know how can I use my message error?". call
such as RuleFor(x => x.Category).Empty().WithMessage("not empty");